# async - await not wating for promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, async-await, expo

Im using expo-sql library:
docs are here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/

example: https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/expo/sqlite-example

```
import { SQLite } from 'expo-sqlite';
import { WebSQLDatabase, ResultSet } from 'expo-sqlite/build/SQLite';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('dbName', version);
  interface WebSQLDatabase {
    transaction(callback: (tx: Transaction) => void,
      error?: (error: {[key: string]: any}) => void,
      success?: () => void
    );
  }
  interface Transaction {
    executeSql(sqlStatement: string, args?: any[],
      success?: (transaction: Transaction, resSet: ResultSet) => void,
      error?: (transaction: Transaction, error: {[key: string]: any}) => void
    );
  }
```

So, I'm playing around with react-native and expo-sqlite libraries and trying to convert some functions using callbacks to functions returning Promise like this:

```js
export type SqlArg = number | string;

export interface SqlQuery {
  sql: string;
  args?: SqlArg[];
}

export function transactionAsync(queries: SqlQuery[]): Promise<ResultSet[]> {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let results: ResultSet[] = [];
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      for (let i=0; i<queries.length; i++) {
        const query = queries[i];
        tx.executeSql(query.sql, query.args, (_, resSet) => {
          results.push(resSet);
        }, err => reject(err));
      }
    }, err => reject(err), () => {
      console.log('transaction results', results);
      resolve(results);
    });
  });
}

export class DatabaseService {
  // working code
  // public static createTables(): Promise<ResultSet> {
  //  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  //    transactionAsync([
  //      {
  //        sql: `create table if not exists items(
  //          id integer primary key,
  //          task_name text not null,
  //          datetime integer not null,
  //          mood integer not null,
  //          comment text)`
  //      }
  //    ]).then( (res) => {
  //      resolve(res[0]);
  //    });
  //  });
  //}

  public static async createTables(): Promise<ResultSet> {
    return await transactionAsync([
        {
          sql: `create table if not exists items(
            id integer primary key,
            task_name text not null,
            datetime integer not null,
            mood integer not null,
            comment text)`
        }
      ])[0];
  }
}
```

Now, the following code snippet returns *undefined* first, and then`transaction results...` with correct output is logged.

```js
(async () => {
  console.log(await DatabaseService.createTables());
})();
```

Output is the same if I write:

```js
DatabaseService.createTables()
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

If `DatabaseService.createTables` is written in non-async manner. Code runs as expected. Same output is logged twice.

Any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to `return await` here and `.then(res => console.log(res));` could just be `.then(console.log);`. There's a lot going on here already and you are missing some key elements (where does 'db' come from?). Please create a *minimal test case* that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you please post the working (non-promise) code as well? Especially your usage of the `executeSql` callback makes me suspicious

Comment: @JaredSmith What do you mean there's no need to return await. i need Promise<ResultSet> as return value, otherwise I get compile error

Comment: @TvrtkoMajstorovic there's no need to `await` before returning. Any callers will have to await the promise anyway, and Promises auto-flatten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is I'm awaiting the first element of the returned promise, instead of first element of the awaited function - it should be like this:

```
  public static async createTables(): Promise<ResultSet> {
    return (await transactionAsync([
      {
        sql: `create table if not exists items(
            id integer primary key,
            task_name text not null,
            datetime integer not null,
            mood integer not null,
            comment text)`
      }
    ]))[0];
  }
```